# Import error : no module named pyodbc on Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, pyodbc

I was trying with the following scenario where I wanted to get data from ODBC database using pyodbc.

```
import pyodbc
DBfile = '/home/administrator/test.mdb'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=MDBtools;DBQ='+DBfile)
csr = conn.cursor()
csr.execute("select * from AttendanceLogs")
row=csr.fetchall()
print row
csr.close()
conn.close()
```

I am getting the error as No module named pyodbc.
When the above command script is run through command prompt, things work fine.

I downloaded the pyodbc package from this link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyodbc
and placed it within python package folder under lib, but still the error persists.

Does anyone have a knowledge on this? regarding reading data from an .mdb file on linux ubuntu? Any suggestion would really help me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried installing it using the `pip` package manager instead? Are you using a virtualenv on your system?

Comment: No, I have not tried using pip, but i will try it and no it is not a virtual environ.

Comment: Let me know if it works - also, virtualenvs are a big help with isolating your environments on a per-purpose basis. You don't want to really mess with your system's Python version since it typically does a lot system-wise, and virtualenvs let you run the Python version you need independently with separate libraries per app/purpose. http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old, but I had this same issue with Odoo 10.

It appears that Odoo doesn't look in the Python lib directory, instead it has its own directory for Python modules.
Provided your Python is 32-bit (to match Odoo), try copying the pyodbc.pyd file to the Odoo installation under server.

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-do-i-install-python-modules-in-a-windows-all-in-one-installation-51734